# Как упроситть очистку буфера (в Wininet сохранение содержимого страницы)

Tags: c, wininet

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    HINTERNET hInternet, hFile;
    char buf[1024];
    DWORD bytes_read;
    int finished = 0;
    int i = 0;
    hInternet = InternetOpen("Chrome 100500", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hInternet != NULL) {
        hFile = InternetOpenUrl(hInternet, "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/", NULL, 0L, 0, 0);
        if (hFile != NULL) {

            FILE *f;
            f = fopen("result.txt","w");

            while (!finished) {
                //  Очищаю переменную, чтоб не было что то типо:
                //  предыдущий результат 12345, а последний abc
                //  и получиться в переменной abc45
                for(i=0; i<sizeof(buf); i++) buf[i] = '\0';

                if (InternetReadFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, &bytes_read)) {
                    if (bytes_read > 0) {
                        fputs(buf, f);
                    }
                    else { finished = 1; }
                }
            }
            fclose(f);
            InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Новичек, код собрал из нескольких мест. Все работает отлично. Но волнует такой вопрос. Там где очистка buf, думаю можно как то упростить, не перебирая 1024 позиций. Подскажите как бы вы написали данный код и почему.

Comment: Да если вы просто читаете текст - то и читайте себе... Прочли N байт - потом добавьте `buf[N] = 0`, в смысле `buf[bytes_read] = 0`

Comment: Harry, Что то я не понял как в коде прописать. Можно поболее пример?

Comment: Ваш код не будет сохранять двоичные данные, лучше fwrite вместо fputs - тогда и присваивать не нужно - и цикл не нужен будет.

Comment: В коде добавить `buf[bytes_read] = 0` перед `fputs`

Comment: nick_n_a, так fwrite или fputs лучше использовать? Ты бы как сделал в данной ситуации?

Comment: Я бы на `fwrite` переписал бы.

Comment: Harry nick_n_a, Долго думал почему это записывать перед записью в файл. Потом прочитал главу в книге по типам переменных и понял что да все верно. Получается 0 записывается после окончания нужного количества массива литералов, а далее 0 означает что нужно завершить считывание массива. А еще такой вопрос в книге нуль символ описывается как '\0', а у вас 0. Разницы нет да. Или я не так опять понял?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74144/discussion-between---and-nick-n-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
for(i=0; i<sizeof(buf); i++) buf[i] = '\0';

if (InternetReadFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, &bytes_read)) {
    if (bytes_read > 0) {
        fputs(buf, f);
    }
    else { finished = 1; }
}
```

на

```
if (InternetReadFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, &bytes_read)) {
    if (bytes_read > 0) {
        buf[bytes_read] = 0;
        fputs(buf, f);
    }
    else { finished = 1; }
}
```